# Select all email addresses, implode by ;

Tags: mysql

I need to select all email addresses from a table, but implode them by `;`.  Is it possible for me to do this only utilizing a single MySQL query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`emailAddress` SEPARATOR ';') AS `emails`
FROM table
WHERE id=4
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: Damn, beat me to it by 11 whole seconds :) There is however a limit to this string (`group_concat_max_len`)

Answer (score 6):

Yes,

With [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat). But you should be aware that the default maximum returned length is 1024. Follow the link to see how you can work around this limitation (if needed).

Comment: I had my returned values trunkated a few times because of that.